# Modifying huge (3.5 million row) in Excel

Tags: excel

Have a 3GB CSV file that I'm trying to remove the first 2 rows from.

In Excel, I go to the 'data' tab, then the second button 'From Text/CSV'.  I select the CSV, and it shows me the top 200 rows of the CSV.  The first two are bogus - I want to remove them and re-save the CSV so I can import it into SQL or POWER BI or another.  It's too big to load into Excel, so I select 'load into', and select in the import data window, to "only create connection" and "add this data to the data model"
Once it loads, I double click it, which opens the "Power Query Editor".  From there I click the 'remove rows', 'remove top rows', I type in '2', and 'ok'.  This removes the rows, but my question is how do I now save that file back to a CSV?  I click 'close and load' but that just puts me back to the excel blank cells with the 'queries and connections' window on the right (which now shows the CSV with 2 less rows - 3,500,000 instead of 3,500,002).  Trying to get that back into a CSV file

Comment: I really don't understand why you would want to use excel for this. Have you tried using tail (`tail -n +3 file > file_with_two_lines_less`)?
Or alternatively just use text editor that can handle large files and remove the first two lines (this is going to take a while to write).

Comment: Excel won't accept more than `1 048 576` rows.

Comment: I think Excel is the wrong tool for this, I would use a text reader to open then delete the first two rows then save.

Comment: Or Powershell if you want to automate it.

Comment: I'm just trying to remove the top 2 rows - not trying to use Excel for any other functionality.  I was not aware of 'tail', but will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gentleman,

It sounds that you want to use Excel for something Excel cannot do :
     - Exceeding the possible row count,
     - Using Excel for big data reformating.

I guess the point of interest you are looking for into Excel, is its ability for exportin data to usual dB formats.

The answer to your question is that you better use native and powerful OS tools, either powershell or linux command line, way faster and more aligned with your actual need.

You may use these tools (See above "tail" example) either to adjust your file format, or even to run an export to whatever dB format you need. The 2nd action might be more complicated to achieve, nevertheless the first one is easy to apply.